# How can I get the number of users actively using Lync?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, lync, reporting

How can I report on the number of users actively using Lync in my organisation? I want to be able to find out what the uptake is.

Thought about going through our mail server, but the saved conversations don't go via SMTP. Also wondered if there's a Powershell way to get the date of the last login / last conversation.

I'm using Lync 2010 via Office 365.

Comment: Do you have administrator rights over the Exchange/Lync server ?

Comment: Yes I do. It's O365 (online) with one on-premise server.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very impressive but for Lync Online you can use the [`Get-CsActiveUserReport`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169474(v=exchg.150).aspx) to show the number of active users per tenant on a daily, weekly, monthly or yearly basis

It only works for Lync Online (O365) and I'm not sure how factors in users using on-premises servers

Answer (score 0):

I've used a Powershell script in the past for this sort of thing, and Pat Richard from ehloworld has a really good write up: http://www.ehloworld.com/269